# How to schedule Business Object report changing filter values dynamically

Tags: schedule, business-objects

I'm using SAP BusinessObjects 3.1 and I'd like to know if is possible to schedule a report changing dynamically the value set in a filtered query.

Thanks.

Nico

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking for.  What should change dynamically, and based on what?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that by using publicaton. You will need to follow the below steps...

1. create new publication.
2. Select the source document as report which you want to schedule.
3. define the dyanamic recepients (a list of users whom you want to send the report).
4. select the personalization and define the filter condition.

It will schedule the report and change the where condition dynamically.

Thanks,
Sachin